# Black screen after waking Kubuntu 22.04 LTS from sleep (AMD Radeon RX6700XT + AMD Ryzen 7700X)

Tags: kubuntu, amd-graphics

Title says it.
My Kubuntu 22.04 won't wake up properly from sleep, the screen stays black even though the mouse is visible and I can move it. How could I fix it?
I have AMD Radeon RX6700XT + AMD Ryzen 7700X CPU. I have the AMD drivers from their website installed.